# Basic Ajax with jQuery - Execute PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

For some reason I can't get this to work. All I want to do is that when a button is clicked, (via ajax) a php file is executed. Aka, if I weren't using ajax, we'd be looking at:

```
<a href="file.php">dfgdfg</a>
```

I want the file to be executed without leaving the page.

This is what I've got atm:

```
$(".vote-up").live('click', function(e) {
$.ajax("file.php", function(){
       alert("Executed file");
   });
});
```

That doesn't seem to be working. I'm just really confused how the jQuery ajax function functions in general, without dealing with anything remotely complicated.

Added question:

```
.ajax({
       url: 'includes/login-check-jquery.php',
       success: function (data) {
            if(data == 1){
                alert("Logged in!!!");
            }else{
                window.location = data;
            }
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // executed if something went wrong during call
        if (xhr.status > 0) alert('Error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
        }
    });
});
```

In the above code, if the data returned equals "logged in" than a message box appears. Otherwise it'll redirect to the location (that is sent in data). For some reason this if statement isn't working, but the data is being returned as expected.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php  
if (!$user->logged_in){
    echo "../login/index.php";
}else{
    echo "1";
}
```

?>

Any ideas?

Comment: try replacing `live` with `on` because live is deprecated !
also check that the path to the php file is correct

Comment: This doesn't look wrong to me--are you trying to get a response from the PHP file or just set something off and forget about it?

Comment: Fails to work at all with on (aka, a test alert doesn't fire either).

Comment: Don't need a response. Just need the php file to execute. (It's to check if user is logged in).

Comment: Do you have any debugger setup? if you do have one, (a) Run the debugger (b) click on the link, and check if any PHP code was executed.

Comment: I don't believe your anonymous function will be executed without getting a non-error status code from your web server. You can use something like Firebug or Chrome's built-in developer tools' network tab to see the status code from the request.

Comment: In terms of the javascript side, the alert never fires which seems strange to me.

Comment: Looked at the network tab and yah, errors are coming up, will try to decipher them and see what the issue is :)

Comment: Alright, gotten the issue sorted (was a linkage issue), only issue now is that I need to do a redirect, and from the looks of it you can't do that via standard php functions.

Comment: Can't seem to work out how to do a php redirect using ajax (well really an ajax redirect based on a response from php).

Comment: Look into `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: That makes sense, that's what I was seeing in my search. My biggest confusion is the callback itself. How do I pass data from the php document back to say that the redirect needs to be performed.

Comment: Check @therao's answer--and you might want to ensure you're either passing something back in plaintext or as JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to leave the page, do

```
$(".vote-up").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

And ajax could be updated, if desired to

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function (data) {
        // this is executed when ajax call finished well
        alert('content of the executed page: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // executed if something went wrong during call
        if (xhr.status > 0) alert('got error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
    }
});
```

error callback part could be removed, if you go for simplicity and not usability and some more options could be added by referencing [jquery ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this. Is data a variable that is assigned the value of whatever is returned by the php file?

Comment: From testing it, yes that is the case. Thanks :) This'll work :)

Comment: yes, it is. sorry for quick replies without really finishing reading ;)

Comment: All good. I understand it and I'm getting it working so all good :)

Comment: Put up a question at the end if you have any ideas :)

Comment: try location.href = data, instead of window.location? I am not sure ../ in the urls will work, it has to be / or full path, like /login/index.php or http://your-domain.com/login/index.php or

Comment: The issue is that the if statement is causing the issue some how. Specifically the jQuery side.

Comment: Wow!!! I'm stupid, the 1 didn't need the quotes in the jQuery. That's what caused the issue. WOW :)

Comment: If you haven't yet, you need to install firebug addon with firefox, it makes debugging easier. Takes a little to learn it, but it is a must. Are you using my code for ajax call or yours? If yours, I don't see the data variable anywhere. I am not really familiar with this way of building the call, but you may need to add $.ajax("file.php", function(data){... to your code.

Comment: Yah, didn't include that sorry. Posted now. I use firebug but only understand bits and pieces of it. Eg. I had no idea about the network tab and what it did. Thanks again for all your help :)